# Get the features of Firefox fullscreen mode without maximizing window?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

In other words, how do you use Firefox's fullscreen mode without forcing the window to maximize? In other words, how to get *content only* with a toggle that won't affect other windows.

I know you can turn off toolbars, but I don't want to affect other Firefox windows. I just want one Firefox to go into fullscreen mode (remove all the toolbars and just show content) but not maximize and cover my entire screen (I want to do other work in other windows, and watch the "fullscreen" content as I work).

Comment: You can't. Fullscreen by definition uses **the whole screen**

Comment: Of course, I understand that. I want all of the features of Firefox fullscreen minus "maximize", hence the question.

Comment: You can't. If you have multiple monitors you can full screen Firefox on one and work on the other. Works quite well.

Answer (score -1):

Please try pressing **F11**.If its not working try searching in tools or settings.

Anyways,As DavisPostill said Fullscreen means **wholescreen**.

Comment: F11 *is* Firefox fullscreen mode. I am trying to get *only webpage content*, that is, no tool bars or anything, I just don't want it maximize. And I don't want to try turning off all the toolbars, because Firefox will think I want them off and all the normal windows will lose toolbars. The fullscreen mode would be perfect if it didn't force maximize.